# C# XML deserialization - performance issue

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xmlserializer

I have to parse XML document before deserializing. Does it make sense to reuse parsed result (by creating reader) or there is no performance difference?

```
var root = XDocument.Parse(message).Root;
var type = mes3.Name.LocalName;
if (type == typeOf(SomeType))
{
    var reader = root.CreateReader();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType));
    var someType = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: The only way to answer that properly is to time it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferable to reuse the parsed result by creating a reader instead of deserializing using directly the string message as the string would not be parsed again during deserilization.

If we use a quick and dirty demo program:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Sample_04_03_2014_01
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sample s = new Sample();
            s.Name = "Hello";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sample));
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, s);
            }
            string serialized = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(serialized);

            var root = XDocument.Parse(serialized).Root;
            Sample someType1 = null;
            Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch1.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sample));
                using (var reader = root.CreateReader())
                {
                    someType1 = (Sample)serializer1.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
            stopWatch1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(someType1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch1.Elapsed);

            Sample someType2 = null;
            Stopwatch stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch2.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sample));
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(serialized))
                {
                    someType2 = (Sample)serializer2.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
            stopWatch2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(someType2.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch2.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

then we obtain ~ 30% performance gain for the first method (CreateReader).

> Hello 00:00:00.8825465 Hello 00:00:01.2636450

Answer (score 0):

your code has  same performance with:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(message))
{
  result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

by you have extra objects.....

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
using (FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
       resultclass = (resultclasstype)serializer.Deserialize(xmlFile);
}
```